# Better solution for Python Threading.Event semi-busy waiting

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, events, busy-loop

I'm using pretty standard Threading.Event:
Main thread gets to a point where its in a loop that runs:

```
event.wait(60)
```

The other blocks on a request until a reply is available and then initiates a:

```
event.set()
```

I would expect the main thread to select for 40 seconds, but this is not the case.
From the Python 2.7 source Lib/threading.py:

```
# Balancing act:  We can't afford a pure busy loop, so we
# have to sleep; but if we sleep the whole timeout time,
# we'll be unresponsive.  The scheme here sleeps very
# little at first, longer as time goes on, but never longer
# than 20 times per second (or the timeout time remaining).
endtime = _time() + timeout
delay = 0.0005 # 500 us -> initial delay of 1 ms
while True:
   gotit = waiter.acquire(0)
   if gotit:
       break
   remaining = endtime - _time()
   if remaining <= 0:
       break
   delay = min(delay * 2, remaining, .05)
   _sleep(delay)
```

What we get is a select syscall run every 500us. 
This causes noticeable load on the machine with a pretty tight select loop.

Can someone please explain why there is a balancing act involved and why is it different than a thread waiting on a file descriptor.

and second, Is there a better way to implement a mostly sleeping main thread without such a tight loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently got hit by the same problem, and I also tracked it down to this exact block of code in the `threading` module.

It sucks.

The solution would be to either overload the threading module, or migrate to `python3`, where this part of the implementation has been fixed.

In my case, migrating to python3 would have been a huge effort, so I chose the former.  What I did was:

1. I created a quick `.so` file (using `cython`) with an interface to `pthread`.  It includes python functions which invoke the corresponding `pthread_mutex_*` functions, and links against `libpthread`.  Specifically, the function most relevant to the task we're interested in is [pthread_mutex_timedlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html).
2. I created a new `threading2` module, (and replaced all `import threading` lines in my codebase with `import threading2`).  In `threading2`, I re-defined all the relevant classes from `threading` (`Lock`, `Condition`, `Event`), and also ones from `Queue` which I use a lot (`Queue` and `PriorityQueue`).  The `Lock` class was completely re-implemented using `pthread_mutex_*` functions, but the rest were much easier -- I simply subclassed the original (e.g. `threading.Event`), and overridden `__init__` to create my new `Lock` type. The rest just worked.

The implementation of the new `Lock` type was very similar to the original implementation in `threading`, but I based the new implemenation of `acquire` on the code I found in `python3`'s `threading` module (which, naturally, is much simpler than the abovementioned "balancing act" block). This part was fairly easy.

(Btw, the result in my case was 30% speedup of my massively-multithreaded process.  Even more than I expected.)

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with you, this is lame.

Currently, I'm sticking with a simple select call, without timeout, and listening on a pipe created before.
The wakeup is done by writing a character in the pipe.

See this [sleep](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/5b7696f032eeb5bb3607b52138e8da599469bd94/gunicorn/arbiter.py#L304) and [wakeup](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/5b7696f032eeb5bb3607b52138e8da599469bd94/gunicorn/arbiter.py#L284) functions from gunicorn.