# Sleep takes 86% of time in rabbitpy consumer?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I found a rather interesting problem today. I have a queue with 2K messages in it. 
The consumer: `import rabbitpy
with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
    with conn.channel() as channel:
        queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, 'example')
        for message in queue.consume_messages():
            message.ack()`

takes 41 seconds to get these messages and `ack` them. (messages vary from `4kB to 52kB`)
The publisher, however, took 15 seconds to publish them.

Upon profiling, I found that there is a call to `sleep` were we spend **86%** of the time. This, to my application, is not acceptable. Could someone help me get rid of this sleep? (I'm ok if the CPU cycles are wasted or whatever till a message arrives.)

[Zoomed in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l88An.png)
[image: The culprit found by the profiler]

Comment: Bigger image link : http://i.imgur.com/K5ce3fV.png

Comment: Done :). I had assumed that it'd be clickable.

Comment: Is this python2.x? It might be related to [the "balancing act" problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9709022/2096752).

Comment: Whoa, what's that! I'm going to try that.. Thanks @shx2

Comment: The problem, however, is I am not sure how to proceed with this *creating a quick .so file.....*

Comment: The first step would be to check if your problem goes away with python3, in order to find out if the two problems are related.

Comment: aye.. but for that, I'd have to compile py3 :( (I'm on AWS).. I'll post back my result.. but idk if you'd be available

Comment: the one in the question is definitely an SSCCE. Also, with some options (shots in the dark) http://paste.ubuntu.com/7710186/

Comment: Interesting thing is.. pypy2.7 did it in 15 seconds, while py3 still took ~32 seconds.

Comment: @shx2, pypy did it. It works like magic. I'll profile the code and post it as an asnwer as soon as time permits. Sincere thanks!